# How to take screenshot of a uiview and drag in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nskeyedarchiver, uilongpressgesturerecogni

i got the code but its not working, let me know if im did anything wrong.
In the code i have a imageview which i created programmatically and adding the image into a uiview.Right now im unable to load the image in the "draggingView".

```
func longPressed(_ sender : UILongPressGestureRecognizer){

    let locationInView = sender.location(in: self.view)
    let cell = sender.view as? ParamterCollectionViewCell
    var tImageView: UIImageView!
    tImageView.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: 30 , height:30)
    tImageView.image = parameterImageArray[0]

    switch sender.state {
    case .began:
        // create an NSData object from myView
        let archive = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: tImageView!)

        // create a clone by unarchiving the NSData
       draggingView = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: archive) as? UIView

        self.view.addSubview(draggingView!)
        draggingView!.center = locationInView;
        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: draggingView!)

        break

    case .changed:
        if (contentView.frame.contains(locationInView)) {
            draggingView?.center = locationInView;
        }
        break

    case .ended:
        break

    default:
        break

}
```

}
}

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? What's "not working"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try... Very similar in idea to your code, but I think it might be a bit better of an approach:

```
func longPressed(_ sender : UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    let locationInView: CGPoint = sender.location(in: self.view)
    let locationInCollectionView: CGPoint = sender.location(in: self.collectionView)

    if sender.state == .began {
        if let indexPath: IndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: locationInCollectionView) {
            if let cell = self.collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) {

                UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(cell.bounds.size)
                cell.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
                let cellImage: UIImage? = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

                self.movingCellImageView = UIImageView(image: cellImage)
                self.movingCellImageView?.alpha = 0.75

                self.view.addSubview(self.movingCellImageView!)
                self.movingCellImageView?.center = locationInView
            }
        }
    }
    // Move movingCellImageView following finger position
    if sender.state == .changed {
        self.movingCellImageView?.center = locationInView
    }
    // Remove movingCellImageView when ended
    if sender.state == .ended {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.movingCellImageView?.alpha = 0
        }, completion: { (success: Bool) in
            self.movingCellImageView?.removeFromSuperview()
            self.movingCellImageView = nil
        })
    }
}
```

References:

Tim Puckett - https://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2014/07/creating-a-draggable-uicollectionviewcell/

Swift implementation by Chan Jing Hong 
http://eatliftswift.weebly.com/technical/creating-a-draggable-uicollectionviewcell